# How to add input field validation for url using Angular.js/Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

i need one help.I need to validate the input field for URL.I am explaining my code below.

```
<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
 <span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right oditek-form" style="width:180px" id="identitylabel">Website URL:</span>
<input type="text" name="url" id="weburl" class="form-control oditek-form" placeholder="Add Website URL" ng-model="url" ng-keypress="clearField('weburl');">
</div>
```

Here right now i can entry any URL of any format.suppose user is entering one `URL` like `www.angon.com` then it should throw the validation error to add `http/https` in beginning of the `URL`.Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use add `type="url"` to your input field, so that would verify value of input field and by verify its valid URL or not it will add `ng-invalid` class over input field.

**Markup**

```
<input type="url" name="url" id="weburl" 
  class="form-control oditek-form" placeholder="Add Website URL" 
  ng-model="url" ng-keypress="clearField('weburl');"/>
```

Refer Examples  :- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Burl%5D

ng-pattern "- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern

Comment: Ok,what is the pattern to display that validation..?

Comment: Have you checked the Documentation ? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern

Comment: @N.V.Prasad don't worry. I did +1 and edited with some brief explanation.